# CSS - Force image to have same width and height of a span

Tags: javascript, css

I have put an image on a span like this:

```
 word_span.append('<a id="imagelink" href="'+ image.link +'" " target="_blank"><img  src="' + image.src +'" border="2px"    /></a>')
```

The css code for span element is like this:

```
span.m10 {

height:90px;
width:90px;

}
```

What I need to do is to force image to be contained in the dimensions of the span. 
Ι've noticed that the image is not displayed with the dimensions of the span, but keeps the proportion of the original size.
It follows just the width of the span but not the height.

Why might this happen?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use the image as background-image to the span you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `span` element is an inline element in HTML. You can not specify a width and height for an inline element.

With that said, you can make the span behave like an `inline-block` like so

```
.m10 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
}
```

Then you tell the image inside the span to use the full width available

```
.m10 img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You might want to consider just letting the `span` display as a `block` element instead. IE does not support inline elements being displayed as `inline-block`. Though, then you might aswell change the `span` to a `div` and save you some time.

Comment: As asker said width only working and but height is not working so your opinion is good catch. +1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using something on the image in your CSS to constrain the image to be only 100% width of the parent? Such as:

```
span.m10 > a > img{
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

This would mean the image would never go beyond the parent container

Comment: `span.m10 > img` is just for img in first level. your mean is `span.m10 > a > img`

Answer (score 1):

To change image proportions use background for span (div) as described below

```
div
{
    background-image:url('image.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your `span` `display:block;` to make it behave like a block container.

Try this

```
span.m10 {
    height:90px;
    width:90px;
    display:block;
}

 #imagelink {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

 .m10 img {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kn5Vu/2/)**

Comment: Thank you, it also worked. I first tried the answer above, that's why I voted it.